# Perl - MySQL - How to tune dB and/or code for read loop

Tags: mysql, performance, perl

DI have a task table which contains provisioning tasks to be completed for different systems.  Each system has a separate Perl process which runs continuously and checks the table to see if it has any uncompleted tasks for that given system.  In the course of a month there can be a few hundred thousand records in this table.  The psuedo code looks like this:

```
select oldest uncompleted task for a given provisioning system
if found a task
  update task to "in progress"
  go do some work
  update task to completed
sleep 15 seconds
repeat
```

Trying to figure out how to make this process more efficient.  If I reduce the sleep time, I add additional load on the DB, but if I increase the sleep time, the overall response of the system gets really sluggish.  Ideally, I would like to completely eliminate the sleep, but without the additional load.

Is there something like an SQL equivalent of a blocking read?  So a select statement will block until it has something to return?

I have thought about having another table with only a list of tasks which are incomplete.  But I would still have to do a join to the large table, so not sure if that would really buy me anything.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is perhaps to have insert triggers on the table which would perhaps touch a file in /tmp.  Then the Perl program could poll the timestamp on that file.  Or perhaps send a small message to a named pipe that the Perl program is listening on with a blocking read.

I would appreciate any help on how to solve this problem.  This kind of dB polling has to be a somewhat common pattern.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anyone ask how to do a SELECT statement that _doesn't_ block, but the consensus seems to be that it's not really possible, so you're probably going to have to find a "least worst" between database engine load and process responsiveness.

Comment: That said, SELECT queries shouldn't put any noticeable load on the database no matter how large the table. If you add your SELECT query, plus the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT [...]` (just prepend EXPLAIN to the same SELECT query you're using, and post the output), plus the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE _table_` for each _table_ involved in the query, then I may well be able to suggest where you could add indexes for a significant performance gain.

Comment: (As a parenthetical note, 'dB' is the standard abbreviation for the decibel. Seeing it used to refer to a database is unusual and a little jarring; may I suggest 'db' or simply 'database' instead?)

Answer (score 0):

Some observations. It's difficult to provide a clear answer because "best" will depend on many factors.

Firstly, you need to decide what is more important - load on the database or speed of processing. Probably a balance between the two.

If it really is vital that you limit activity on the db then you'll want something centralised. Simplest might be a pending_tasks table that contains ids and timestamps. A separate manager process keeps that table topped up and picks timestamps according to overall load. You'll need to make sure that process never stops of course.

Another option is to have each processor vary its sleep time. If there is nothing to do, add one second. If there is something to do, subtract one second. Obviously, have a min/max for the sleep times. You can get cleverer with the variations if you like.

That way, each processor will tend to rest while there is nothing to do.

Third observation - you have one process for each system. Just fetch the next 10 tasks (or whatever). Just don't mark them as in progress until you actually start work.

Finally, this sort of asynchrous communication you would really like is available elsewhere. In PostgreSQL they are called notifications. I'm afraid I'm not aware of any similar feature in MySQL.

HTH